# makefile compile multiple source files in one call

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

Imagine that I have 2 source files that both include one header file.
a.c:

```
#include "ab.h"

int a() {
    return RETURN_VAL;
}
```

b.c:

```
#include "ab.h"

int b() {
    return !RETURN_VAL;
}
```

ab.h:

```
#define RETURN_VAL (0)
```

I want a makefile that can compile in one call a.c and b.c. If ab.h is new or a.c and b.c are both new, then I want:
gcc -c a.c b.c
touch ab.timestamp
Otherwise I want to recompile only the out of date files.

This is a tiny example, I need something that scales. I have attempted to resolve this, but I can't figure out how.

This is an example using C, but my actual use is for compiling large-scale HDL projects. As the invocation of the HDL compilers has a high overhead, it is much better to call the tool once for many files instead of separately for each.

What I have tried are things like:

```
a.c: ab.h ;
b.c: ab.h ;

ab.timestamp: a.c b.c
  gcc -c $?
  touch ab.timestamp
```

This won't work, and instead I need something like this:

```
ab.timestamp: a.c b.c ab.h
  gcc -c a.c b.c
  touch ab.timestamp
```

This is what I don't want. I would like $? to indicate the correct files that I need to recompile. I know that I can use $(if and $(filter functions to figure this out, but I was hoping for something more seamless.

I am using GNU Make.

Thanks,
Nachum

Comment: Why doesn't the first version with the `$?` work?  In what way does it fail?  I created a sample makefile and it worked for me.

Comment: touch ab.h, and then make. make will consider ab.timestamp up to date b/c a.c and b.c aren't new.

Comment: Well, sure, because you don't create a .c file from a .h file.  Even if make built the timestamp it wouldn't do what you want, because since the .h file has a newer timestamp than the .c file it would ALWAYS be considered out of date, until you modified the .c file to be newer.

Comment: yes, and this is the point of the question. is there a way to accomplish what i want. I see that on the list of desired enhancements there is a request for an inclusion type prerequisite. that would do what i want. the .h would be an inclusion prerequisite of the .c files. do you know how i can accomplish this without such an enhancement?

Comment: I don't think the enhancement you mention would help you.  What I was trying to say is that what you want is not possible, because there's no way for make to know when a file has been properly updated.  Make doesn't keep its own database of update information: it relies on the filesystem modification times, and only those.  Since you are not changing the target (.c) timestamp, once you change the .h file the next run of make will still consider the .c file out of date.  And the run after that, etc., until the .c file mod time is updated in some way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a trick, but it might work:

```
all: ab.timestamp

SOURCES = a.c b.c ab.h
a.o: a.c ab.h
b.o: b.c ab.h

CHANGED :=
%.o: %.c ; $(eval CHANGED += $<)

ab.timestamp: $(SOURCES) $(patsubst %.c,%.o,$(filter %.c,$(SOURCES)))
        gcc -c $(CHANGED)
        touch $@
```

Comment: Um... this doesn't seem to work. Or rather, it works too much. If only `a.c` has changed, it still recompiles both sources.

Comment: It works for me.  On my system, `gcc -c foo.c bar.c` will create two object files, `foo.o` and `bar.o`.  Does that not happen on your system?  In that case if you touch `a.c` it should only notice that `a.o` is out of date and try to rebuild it, and that will add only `a.c` to the `CHANGED` variable.

Comment: **I was wrong.** I took a shortcut to monitor `CHANGED` without actually compiling, and disrupted the actual construction of the variable. This makefile works.

Comment: And this is exactly the complexity I was hoping to avoid... Sucks that there is no seamless way to do this.

Comment: There cannot be seamless ways to support every possible use-case.  The further you get away from the standard model, the more seams you'll encounter.  This is no less true of makefiles than any other language.

Answer (score 0):

This is a kludge, but it seems to work. Touch the source files to bring them up to date with the header:

```
a.c b.c: ab.h
    @touch $@

ab.timestamp: a.c b.c
    gcc -c $?
    touch ab.timestamp
```

Comment: This may work, but it's a bummer to be touching source files like this.  Many editors, for example, will treat the change in timestamp as if the file has been modified by some other process and require you to reload it.  It's not nice if, after every build, all your editor's buffers are out of date.

Comment: @MadScientist: I agree, it has drawbacks.

Comment: I did this first, to try and figure out what I wanted. But of course I don't want to touch files for all the reasons already mentioned.